# c#: trying to use Regular Expressions to match a phrase

Tags: c#, regex

I trying to use a regular expression in C# to search for multi-word phrase.  For example, I am currently pulling data data from a SQL Server table and I need to find a user-input keyword search "Hello World".  This match could be at the beginning of a record, end of a record or anywhere in-between.  I can match single word keyword wothout a problem.

Thanks in advance.

Found my answer: @"(\b)+" + strKeyword.txt + @"(\b)+";
At least it works!

Comment: Please show us your code, we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score 6):

For multi word matching use 
`Match match = Regex.Match(text, @"(?:(hello world))")` 
But to solve your problem follow the method @gabba has posted.

Comment: You have two useless groups around your regex. `@"hello World"` would match exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you use direct sql query use

   `select * from table where field like '%Hello World%'`
2. If you use Linq use contains method

   `var res = from rec in records where rec.field.Contains("Hello World") select rec`
3. If you have a collection with data you can match every element like this

   `records.Where(x => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(x.field, @"(?:(hello world))")).ToList();`
4. If you have string variable just use Regex:
   `string variable = "bla bla Hello World woop";

   bool isExsistsReg = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(variable, @"Hello    World");`

Comment: well, we are a little behind the times, we are using Visual Studio 2005, .Net 2.0, SQL Server 2005 and no Linq

Comment: Also, the search text is in a variable: